# Proportional Editing - Limit to selected?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, transforms

This seems an obviously desirable option for proportional editing: to be able to transform only selected elements, using, say, the active element as the center of falloff. Is there a Blender way to achieve this reasonably quickly?

I know it can be done by hiding the elements you wish to remain untransformed, but often you want to see them during the transformation.

Comment: nope. proportional editing works by affecting the surrounding unselected vertices.

Comment: I wonder whether there are any major obstructions to scripting this, apart from my lack of expertise. I imagine you could use vertex weights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One workaround is to select the vertices that you want to leave unaffected and press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them. Proportional editing will only have effect on the visible geometry.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in the OP, that does seem to be the Blender way, at the moment, but I really would like to see the unaffected geometry while I'm shoveling stuff around.

Answer (score 2):

In Object Mode, simply lock the transforms of the objects you don't want to be affected : in the Properties pannel (T), clic the locks next to the Location/Rotation/Scale properties.

In Edit mode, I don't think it's possible.